# std::map<int, std::bitset<256 > > thread safety w/o mutex?

Tags: c++, dictionary, thread-safety, race-condition, bitset

I have a

```
std::map<int, std::bitset<256 > > m;
```

After construction no new keys will be inserted and no keys will be removed. Can I safely assign the bitset in one thread while reading it in other threads without using a mutex?

```
// thread 1: 
std::bitset<256> a = getBitset();
m[1] = a;  

// thread 2:
std::bitset<256> b = m[1]; 
// or alternatively 
std::bitset<256> c = m.at(1);
```

I think that the program will not crash but a data race could occur in the bitset. A data race would be acceptable if the read would deliver a combination of the old and the new bitset.

Comment: std::bitset<256> b; ...; m[1] = b;

Comment: I have modified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not safe.

`operator=` of the `bitset` is a modifying operation, and as such is not guaranteed to be free of a data race if the `bitset` is simultaneously accessed in another thread. And in practice, it will almost surely cause a data race, since it needs to write to the object. This is not specific to `std::bitset`, but generally true for pretty much all non-empty non-atomic standard library types (and most other non-empty types, as well).

Any data race will result in undefined behavior. There are no partial updates. In that sense, it should never be acceptable.

If you want to be able to do this, either wrap the `bitset` in a `struct` with a `mutex` to protect access to the `bitset`, or use something like an atomic `shared_ptr` that allows atomically exchanging the old `bitset` with a new one and delaying destruction of the old one until all references are gone.

Although I think it is not guaranteed, `std::bitset` may also be trivially copyable. You could check that with a `static_assert` on `std::is_trivially_copyable_v` and if `true`, you could also use a [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) which will allow accessing the bitset atomically (i.e. free of data race) and will probably use a lock only if the underlying architecture doesn't support atomic access to an object of the corresponding size.

Also note that `std::bitset b = m[1];` and `m[1]` also cause undefined behavior, because `operator[]` of `std::map` is also a modifying operation, and is not specified to be free of a data race, even if it doesn't insert a new element into the map. You would need to use e.g. the `find()` member function instead.

Comment: Regarding the map: Do you mean that concurrent reads with [] are not safe or do you mean that it is safe to write with [] in one thread while reading the content with find()?

Comment: @ErnieMur `operator[]` counts as a write operation for the purpose of data race avoidance. So `[]` and `.find` in two threads is also a data race. (Although in this case if the `[]` operation doesn't insert a new element, I would guess that most implementations will be free of data races. There is no guarantee though.)

Comment: As long as no new keys are being added, then it will likely be safe to use `operator[]` just for reading the `map` in multiple threads, but like user17732522 said, it is not *guaranteed* to be safe.

Comment: Is [] of std:map generally not thread-safe or would be a std::map<int, uint64_t> be thread-safe on a 32bit cpu or at least on a 64bit cpu - if the value is only read and written and no entries are removed or inserted?

Comment: @ErnieMur The `operator[]` issue is independent of the key and value type. It applies to `std::map` as such, although as noted above, as long as you don't insert a new element, you are not likely to run into trouble in practice (still I don't recommend relying on it). In case of the assignment, that will be a data race and undefined behavior for pretty much all non-atomic key or value types. The architecture doesn't matter. A data race on a non-atomic object is always UB according to the standard and compilers may optimize based on that.